# Website security - Does php or webserver strip details before returning html?

Tags: php, security, iis

I am replacing an existing very old site written in another lang with a newly-coded php site and I need to double-check a couple of things with respect to security.  Website will be running on Windows 2008 R2 using IIS 7.5 and running php 5.3.8.

I am storing db login creds in a file outside of web root.  But in my php code I have to include those files and I am using an absolute path.  Will php and/or IIS strip out the file path.  (I imagine the answer is yes since competing technologies would do likewise, but need to be sure on this and couldn't find the answer.)

On a related point, what is the best place to keep .js files?  Is it better security-wise to keep them outside of web root?

Sorry for the basic questions, but am new to php (long time programmer in other langs).

Comment: PHP and the webserver, by default, in standard configurations, will NOT modify what you send out.They have absolutely NO way of knowing that's "private" and "public" - your include path is just going to be a sequence of text characters like any other. If something's outside your webroot, then by definition it's not accessible, and any JS code you require to be loaded by the clients will be utterly broken.

Comment: To supplement Marc's answer, where you place the js files on your server is trivial; they're going to be sent to the client anyways (in their entirety) so whether they came from `js/app.js` or `/Super/Secret/Path/app.js` is moot--the client's still going to be executing it.

Comment: So you are saying that php doesn't parse out commands and their parameters. E.g., if in my php file I add the command: require 'xyz\abc.php' then the file that gets returned from a browser or curl request includes the full path? –

Comment: the point I am making is that there is a command "require" that takes a path as a parameter.  The question is doesn't php and the webserver strip out the command and it its parameters?  I can't really believe it doesn't parse the php code and strip out the php and associated params.  Otherwise everyone in the universe would have their internal paths displayed to everyone else any time a config file is included.

Comment: Never mind.  I just tested this myself.  If you use a php command like: require 'c:\xyz\abc.php' neither the command nor the path are included in the source returned to the browser or curl command, etc.  So the parser and webserver DO strip out the commands and associated params.

Comment: Sadly I cannot close this question until tomorrow.  So more replies are welcome but I think I have the answers I need unless someone sees something wrong with my previous comment.

Comment: @Pete, I think your confusion is in how PHP works.  PHP, and everything else like it, is running on the server, not the client.  None of your PHP source code is ever sent to the client.  Any credentials or whatever are safe on the server as long as you don't expose them in some way.

Answer (score 0):

well, php is different from ASP, so my suggestion is to make a subdomain for js/css, you even can name it [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)... but, it still better than from the root.

Comment: I did say it was outside of the root.  But are you saying it should not be included as an absolute path outside of the root and instead create a new subdomain?

Comment: I also tested this question.  In the case of js or css, those files and the paths associated with them are fully visible since they are in the html and so are not parsed out by php / web server.

Answer (score 0):

I ran a bunch of tests where I looked at the source of what is returned by php and the webserver.  If you use the php command "require c:\abc\file.php" neither piece of information is returned with the html.

However, the path to a .js file IS displayed. This is because it sits inside the html, not php, so that path is NOT stripped out by php or the webserver.

So from this I think I can safely say:
1. The path to the creds will not be displayed in the html source returned to the browser or curl call or whatever.
2. js and css paths are shown publicly so it is worth considering whether these need to be secured (e.g., separate subdomain or similar).